# Overwrite functions.php of a theme - What if the theme is updated?

Tags: themes, shortcode

I have added a shortcode inside a functions.php file of my a Theme.

I am wondering that if the theme changes, it might overwrite the current functions.php file. So, is this true? If so, where should I place my shortcode so that even if I update the theme it doesn't go away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general [Child Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) are meant to be used for customizations on upstream parent theme.

However views differ for specific types of customizations. Since shortcodes are related to your content a lot, it might be more robust to considering putting them into simple plugin (or ["must use" plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins)).